# Как и насколько сложно реализовать механизм изменения кода во время работы программы?

Tags: java

Мои познания пока только опираются на синтаксис и в глубь пока сильно со всяким не уходил, но интересует такая тема, и попросил бы кого то прокомментировать и по возможности ответить :

Как и насколько сложно реализовать механизм изменения кода во время работы программы, и какие в таком механизме недостатки и преимущества (помимо пожалуй того что код будет динамически изменен там без необходимости повторно все компилировать)

Comment: Самые зловредные вирусы используют технику изменения кода, чтобы усложнить задачу антивирусу по его поимке. Очевидно в данном случае имеем преимущества. В подавляющем большинстве других - а на фига это надо?

Comment: @Sergey, самый распространенный Java фреймворк использует кодогенерацию направо и налево. AOP - тоже. Большие кровавые энтерпрайзные решения генерируют entity-классы на лету из конфигурации. Профайлеры используют инструментацию кода через Java Agent.

Comment: @Nofate Но это же происходит до того, как код загружен на выполнение, при загрузке класса всяким instrumentation меняется код. Не во время же выполнения? Энтерпрайзы генерят код своих прокси и не меняют его потом уже во время работы и никогда не меняют код классов, для которых генерятся эти прокси.

Comment: @Sergey, с точки зрения приложения классы появляются в runtime. Оборачивая исходный класс в динамически сгенерированные proxy, можно менять поведение одного и того же экземпляра объекта.  Это не совсем "честное" метапрограммирование как в Groovy, но достаточно неплохая "иллюзия".

Answer (score 4):

Есть такой термин "Метапрограммирование".

Определение из википедии:
*"вид программирования, связанный с созданием программ, которые порождают другие программы как результат своей работы(в частности, на стадии компиляции их исходного кода), либо программ, которые меняют себя во время выполнения (самомодифицирующийся код)." Первое позволяет получать программы при меньших затратах времени и усилий на кодирование, чем если бы программист писал их вручную целиком, второе позволяет улучшить свойства кода (размер и быстродействие).*

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

А вот статья про метапрограммирование конкретно на Java:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/91239/

Почитайте и погуглите еще материалы про метапрограммирование, думаю, что что-то интересное для себя найдете.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще интересная техника изменения логики программы на лету называется аспекты, программирование с помощью аспектов называется аспектно-ориентированным программированием.